# How to use XPATH to search for a span with a class for Selenium Testing in JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am working on a piece of code which wants me to select the span with the class `amountCharged` and get the value of that span to test it against the mock value. The problem that I am facing is that I cannot seem to select that `span` using `XPath`. I have tried multiple ways and still fail, I went on **W3Schools** and **Stackoverflow** questions but was unable to nail the syntax.

Below is the error I am facing:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for text ('£163.06') to be present in element found by `By.xpath:`

 //span[contains(@class, 'amountCharged')]
```

As you can see I am trying to use `//span[contains(@class,'amountCharged')]` as the `XPATH`, same issue with using "

```
/descendant::span[contains(@class, 'amountCharged')]
```

THE HTML STARTING FROM A PARENT DIV IS:

```
    <div class="panelMessage instructional" params="">    Total:         
 <span class="amountCharged">£163.06</span> quoted on          
<span class="reservationTime">Tue, 29 Nov 2011 15:46 GMT</span> . </div>
    </div>        
<div class="panelContent hideFocus noneBlock  " tabindex="-1" data-  context="panelContent">
```

The JAVA code is:

```
   private static void elementShouldContain(String locator, String value, String errorMessage, long timeout) {
    String xpath = buildLocator(locator, "");
    WebDriverWait customWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriverInstance, timeout / 1000);
    try {
    customWait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.xpath(xpath), value));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handles the specific exception, except that the message is null, in which case throws a regular SeleniumException
        if (errorMessage != null)
            throw new CustomSeleniumException(errorMessage, e);
        else
            throw new SeleniumException(e);
    }
}
```

what am I missing please help.

Thank You

Comment: It'd be good to show the HTML from which your XPath is intended to select.

Comment: your error message indicates that it can't find the particular text, but it does find the element

Comment: I have pasted the HTML, and the text 163.06 is there

Comment: Is there more element with `amountCharged` name present?

Comment: No, in the entire HTML there is just one span with this class. And it selects the span when I do it through chrome reg x checker

Comment: And, I want to see how you get the text as well. Meaning what are you using to get the `span` text

Comment: /descendant::span[contains(@class, 'amountCharged')]/text()[last()] I tried this and compared it to a hard coded String "£163.06"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error you've mentioned, **I suppose you are using [textToBePresentInElement](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElement(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement,%20java.lang.String)) or [textToBePresentInElementLocated](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By,%20java.lang.String)) or something related method under the [ExpectedConditions class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)**.

You can alternatively do this:
**1- Wait for the visibility of the element using [Explicit Wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

2- Retrieve the text

3- Assert/Compare the text with the value: '£163.06'.**

You can try the below code that comprises of all above in order:

```
    String text_in_panel=null;
    try{
        //waiting 20 seconds for the visibility of the element
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'panelMessage')]/span[1]")));

        //Retrieving the text from the element
        text_in_panel = element.getText();
    }catch(Throwable e){
        System.err.println("Element is not visible: "+e.getMessage());
    }

    //Comparing the text with the hard-coded value
    if(text_in_panel.equals("£163.06"))
        System.out.println("Text matches");
    else
        System.err.println("Text doesn't match");
```

**[OR You can assert the values instead of comparing them, using the Assert class by importing import junit.framework.Assert;]**

```
    //Assert the text with the hard-coded value
    try{
        Assert.assertEquals(text_in_panel, "£163.06");
        System.out.println("Text matches");
    }catch(Throwable e){
        System.err.println("Text doesn't match");
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Couple of things to keep that in mind:

1. Testing the `xpath` on Chrome debugger of Firebug does not necessarily mean that the `selector` is going to return the target element uniquely. There might be some other elements hidden with same selector and `webdriver` will fail to find the target element in that case. For debugging purpose use `findElements` a see how many elements it returns.
2. Element loading issue such as: visibility can also be another issue. That's why you need to make sure the element is present and visible. Use [explicit](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) wait

Try following `xpaths`

```
//span[@class='amountCharged']
```

If the class is not unique and you want to find the `span` depending on the div you can do the following:

```
//div[contains(@class,'panelMessage ')]//span[@class='amountCharged']
```

Comment: I actually got this to work using Chrome debugger but my test still thinks that it is not there. /descendant::span[contains(@class, 'amountCharged')]/text()[last()]

Comment: I would like to see the test code and `stacktrace` you get then

Comment: @alyn000r If you care about getting an answer, show the _complete_ HTML and test code. We don't like being in the dark (and neither would you, I think).

Comment: I have added the JAVA code here too sorry for not adding it earlier. I cannot put the entire HTML due to company policies.